# How to get VHost Server Name with Java?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxy, vhosts

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

i'm getting a bit confused with getting the Servername of a Vhost. Im working with my apache and a Tomcat. The Apache is redirecting the Requests to my Tomcat to start a Function.
The Point is that i have to identify the Servername. The purpose is to get the Servername and decide like if the servername is like office23.de then the server has to load the configuration for office23 if other office then load other configurations. I hope i could explain it a bit.

What i did so far:

i added into Tomcat's server.xml :

also added in Apache's httpd.conf:

```
ProxyRequests on

ProxyPass         /getTest/  http://localhost:8080/Test/
ProxyPassReverse  /getTest/  http://localhost:8080/test/
```

and the lines to load the mod_proxy stuff.

additional i configured the httpd-vhosts.conf like this:

ServerName js.local.test.de

```
DocumentRoot "D:/downloads/xampp/tomcat/webapps"

<Directory />
    Require all granted
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog "D:/downloads/xampp/apache/logs/virtualHost.log"
CustomLog "D:/downloads/xampp/apache/logs/customLog.log" common
```

i can reach my application through the vhost adress but when i try to get the Host Header it says that its localhost:8080.

I also changed the windows hostfile.

**Does any opurtunity excist that allows me to get the vhost name?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enable [ProxyPreserveHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) on the reverse proxy, the Host: header is kept in the request to the proxy, instead of being replaced with the hostname specified in the ProxyPass (localhost, in your case).  That should help you get the right name on the back-end.

Mangling the hosts file won't do you any good, and if you forget you did that, it'll probably come back to haunt you, later on.

Comment: You cant imagine how much u helped me :-)